# Avoiding duplicates while adding jsonobjects into the jsonarray using java

Tags: java, json

I have a list of objects and am converting into JSONArray. Am iterating over the JSONObjects and making an array of JSONObjects.

Now, i want to avoid duplicates objects to get insert into the JSONArray.

Please find my java code below.

```
JSONArray responseArray1 = new JSONArray();
if (!itemList.isEmpty())
{
  jsonArray = new JSONArray(itemList);
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
  {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
    String attr_label = jsonObj.optString("attr_label");
    if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(attr_label, "long_description")) {
        long_description = jsonObj.optString("value");
    }
    else if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(attr_label, "description")) {
        description = jsonObj.optString("value");
    }
    responseObj.put("id", jsonObj.opt("id")); // i will get duplicate id
    responseObj.put("code", jsonObj.opt("code")); // i will get duplicate code
    responseObj.put("long_description", long_description);
    responseObj.put("description", description);
    responseArray1.put(responseObj);

  }
}
```

Please find my actual jsonArray :

```
[  
   {  
      "code":"xyaz",
      "attr_label":"long_description",
      "id":"12717",
      "value":"Command Module"
   },
   {  
      "code":"xyaz",
      "attr_label":"description",
      "id":"12717",
      "value":"Set Point Adjustment"
   },
]
```

Am expecting like the below jsonArray :

```
[  
   {  
      "code":"xyaz",
      "id":"12717",
      "long_description":"Command Module"
      "description" : "Set Point Adjustment"
   }
]
```

**Update :**

I have tried with the below code to avoid duplicate insertion of `id` & `code` field. but is not working properly. Its inserting duplicates also.

```
List<String> dummyList=new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray responseArray2 = new JSONArray(itemList);
if (!itemList.isEmpty())
{
  jsonArray = new JSONArray(itemList);
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
  {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

    String itemCode = jsonObj.optString("code");
    String id = jsonObj.optString("id");
    if(!dummyList.contains(itemCode) && !dummyList.contains(id) ) {
    dummyList.add(String.valueOf(jsonObj.opt("id")));
    dummyList.add(String.valueOf(jsonObj.opt("code")));
    responseObj.put("id", jsonObj.opt("id"));
    responseObj.put("code", jsonObj.opt("code"));
    responseObj.put("long_description", long_description);
    responseObj.put("description", description);
    responseArray2.put(responseObj);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a temporary array list and add unique code in that arrayList and check if it already exists in arrayList then don't put this again

```
String code = jsonObj.opt("code");
if(!arrayList.contains(code))
{
    arrayList.add(code);
    responseObj.put("id", jsonObj.opt("id")); 
    responseObj.put("code", jsonObj.opt("code")); 
    responseObj.put("long_description", long_description);
    responseObj.put("description", description);
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to use Set then this idea. appreciable!

Comment: replace && with || if(!dummyList.contains(itemCode) || !dummyList.contains(id) )

Answer (score -1):

use TreeSet and add Comparator to their constructor in which it compare the duplicate data of the object.
for example:-

```
     Set<Sample> sampleSet=new TreeSet<>(new Sample());
```

where Sample Class look like:-

```
 class Sample implements Camparator<Sample>{
    private String name;
    private String id;
   //getter 
   //setter

    @Override
    public String compare(Sample o1,Sample o2){
        return o1.getName.compareTo(o2.getName);
    }
    }
```

This will give a set of unique name entries.

Comment: How to add one more attribute in `compare` method. like `getName()` & `getId()`

Comment: Inside campare method there was your logic if you want both name and id shoud be unique then create you own logic and return '0' <zero> on unique id and name like:- if(o1.getName.compareTo(o2.getName)==0)return 0;else if(o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId())==0) return 0; else return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName);

Comment: that approach is good as per javadoc override equals and hashcode method is bad approach.